# Python Tkinter on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, tkinter

I just did a fresh install of Python on Windows 10. I enter "python" and get Python 3.7.4. I tried to import Tkinter and it says "No module named 'Tkinter'. I looked around online and everything said that Tkinter is a standard library that comes with Python. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From python 3, Tkinter module is renamed to [tkinter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html).
Try using `import tkinter` instead.

> Tkinter has been renamed to tkinter in Python 3. The 2to3 tool will automatically adapt imports when converting your sources to Python 3.